# How to leave a row in the table with value of foreign key in, if a row with a foreign key is deleted?

Tags: postgresql

There is table1:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_table1_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
```

There is table2:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  fk_1 integer,
  CONSTRAINT fk_to_table1 FOREIGN KEY (fk_1)
      REFERENCES table1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
      NOT VALID
)
```

When I try to delete some row from table1 I got exception:

```
UPDATE or DELETE in the table "table1" violates the foreign key constraint "fk_to_table1" of the table "table2"
```

Is there some way to leave(save) a row in the table2 with same value in fk_1 (id from table1) if a row with a foreign key from table1 is deleted?

Example:
Table1:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Teble2:

```
id fk_1
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 3
4 | 2
```

What I want to see after delete first row from table1:

Table1:

```
id
2
3
```

Teble2:

```
id fk_1
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 3
4 | 2
```

Comment: It sort of defeats the purpose of a relationship. Maybe if you explain your use case we can find a more _orthodox_ solution?

Comment: It`s education project... Something like a forum, user (table1) can leave messages(table2). If user will be deleted, i want to save his messages and save foreign key to know, that messages was from the same user

Comment: I see, so it's a fair exercise. I believe it's been already answered by @a_horse_with_no_name :-)

Comment: sorry, was not correct in my question... I want to save id of deleted row from table1 in fk_1 in table2

Comment: A `delete from table1` can **not** cause a primary key violation in that table (which is what your error message shows)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: That's not possible and completely contradicts the idea of a foreign key. The only options you have is to either set the FK value to `NULL`, or delete the referencing row. (Or don't delete from table1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `ON DELETE SET NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  fk_1 integer,
  CONSTRAINT fk_to_table1 FOREIGN KEY (fk_1)
      REFERENCES table1 (id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE SET NULL
);

insert into table1 values (1), (2);
insert into table2 values (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2);
```

Then if you run:

```
delete from table1
where id = 1;
```

Table2 will look like this:

```
id | fk_1
---+-----
 1 |     
 2 |     
 3 |    2
 4 |    2
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NPUG18060

Comment: sorry, was not correct in my question... I want to save id of deleted row from table1 in fk_1 in table2

Comment: Idea is to make result of delete STILL contain "1" in fk_1, even when row with "1" deleted from table1

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you cannot.

the purpose of a foreign key is to verify that whenever that attribute has a value, the value is in the referenced table (except when the value is NULL---NULL does not need to exist in the table).

Two suggestions:

Solution 1. Keep the tuple in Table2, do not delete it. Instead, add a boolean attribute that determines is the tuple has been deleted.

Specifically for your problem. Add an attribute deleted to the table.
Set if to default to false. And when the tuple is deleted
create a trigger to set this attribute to true instead. This is cumbersome
and error prone.

Solution 2 (this is my preferred solution). You can use a third table that is managed via triggers.
Every time a tuple in the table2 is added, a tuple to the table3 is
added. Table3 will only have one attribute (the one you want to have
the foreign key referenced to). Table3 will be the set of all values of the attribute that have been part of Table2. The trigger to add to Table3 should use upsert, in case the attribute being added has been seen before.
Table1 will then have the foreign key constraint pointing to Table3.